# Drop unique constraint on column

Tags: sql-server

I have run the following query to add unique constraint on column "name".

```
alter table mytable 
  add unique (name)
```

Now I am trying to remove this constraint, I am getting errors.

Kindly give me a solution.

Thanks

ps. I am using SQL Server

Comment: pl post the error

Comment: Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'name' is not a constraint.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: ALTER TABLE users
DROP CONSTRAINT 'constraints_name'

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'constraints_name'.

Comment: use without single qoutes as

Comment: ALTER TABLE users DROP CONSTRAINT constraints_name

Comment: Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'constraints_name' is not a constraint.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: replace 'constraints_name'  with ur constraint name

Comment: ex:  alter table #temp drop constraint uq_column_name

Comment: thanks for your concern bro. 
let me explain you one more time

I have a single table with 4 columns on of them is 'name'.
I just ran this query to add unique constraint on name
alter table mytable add unique (name) 
and this added the unique constraint to name column.
now I am stuck. I am trying all you're telling me but I am still getting errors

Comment: use this to get the constraint name and then drop  it.in this quesry place the table name at the last select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_TYPE='UNIQUE' and TABLE_NAME='yourtablename'

Comment: Thanks a lot man. this worked for me. 
love you :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125683/discussion-between-yuvi-and-muhamamd-usman).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.mytable DROP CONSTRAINT constraintname;
```